# Program that stores the names and populations of 12 countries two arrays of the same size

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Use data below

Countries: USA, Canada, France, Belgium, Argentina, Luxembourg, Spain, Russia, Brazil, South Africa, Algeria, Ghana

Population in millions: 327, 37, 67, 11, 44, 0.6, 46, 144, 209, 56, 41, 28

### Use two arrays that may be used in parallel to store  the names of the countries and their populations.

### Write a loop that neatly prints each country name and its population.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    
    
    // 12 countries and population size
    
    String[] countryName = {"USA", "Canada", "France", "Belgium", "Argentina", "Luxembourg", 
                            "Spain", "Russia", "Brazil", "South Africa", "Algeria", "Ghana"}; //declare the country
    
    
    int[] populationSize = {327, 37, 67, 11, 44, 1, 
                            46, 144, 209, 56, 41, 28}; // declare the population
                            
    // A parallel array are when the position match each other ex usa postion 0 and 327 position 0
    
    for
    (
            int i = 0; i <=11; i++
    )
            System.out.printf("Country: %s, Population in millions: %d \n", countryName[i], populationSize [i]);
    
        
    
}
```

}

If you notice from the instructions Luxembourg is suppose to be 0.6 but I put 1. Every time I try to make this a double I get an error. Currently im using int but it has to be a double. Any advice I appreciate it. I already tried changing it to double [] but I still get an error. Changed the population size and the loop below from int to double did not work. Error in java

Comment: what is the error??

Comment: Why are you not using an array of doubles, `double[] populationSize`?

Comment: When I use double[] I get an error tried that.

Comment: Error is: cannot convert from double to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the populationSize to array of Double and assign double values
use correct format specifier for double, i have used `%.2f` f is for floating point number, which includes double and 2 says two digits after decimal point

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {


        // 12 countries and population size

        String[] countryName = {"USA", "Canada", "France", "Belgium", "Argentina", "Luxembourg", 
                "Spain", "Russia", "Brazil", "South Africa", "Algeria", "Ghana"}; //declare the country


        Double[] populationSize = {327.0, 37.0, 67.0, 11.0, 44.0, 0.6, 
                46.0, 144.0, 209.0, 56.0, 41.0, 28.0}; // declare the population

        // A parallel array are when the position match each other ex usa postion 0 and 327 position 0

        for (int i = 0; i <=11; i++ ) {
            System.out.printf("Country: %s, Population in millions: %.2f \n", countryName[i], populationSize [i]);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Country: USA, Population in millions: 327.00 
Country: Canada, Population in millions: 37.00 
Country: France, Population in millions: 67.00 
Country: Belgium, Population in millions: 11.00 
Country: Argentina, Population in millions: 44.00 
Country: Luxembourg, Population in millions: 0.60 
Country: Spain, Population in millions: 46.00 
Country: Russia, Population in millions: 144.00 
Country: Brazil, Population in millions: 209.00 
Country: South Africa, Population in millions: 56.00 
Country: Algeria, Population in millions: 41.00 
Country: Ghana, Population in millions: 28.00
```

Comment: Thank you SanjeeRM. I did try the decimals, now noticing it seems the system.out where .2f is what I was missing. This was causing my error

Comment: if it solved your problem, please accept answer and hit upvote